# Delphi 7 Procedure with variant parameters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Have a procedure which looks like

```
Procedure TestProc(TVar1, TVar2 : variant);
Begin
  TVar1 := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  TVar1.Workbooks.open('C:\Test\Test.xls');
  TVar1.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1].Name := 'Sheet_1';
  TVar2 := TVar1.Workbooks[1].Worksheets['Sheet_1'];
End;
```

Note: TVar1 and TVar2 are global variables

Calling the procedure in an onclick event of a button and then using the created objects is not working

Is it that delphi does not allow creation of procedures having variant parameters???

Comment: Note that the `T` prefix is used to denote a type rather than a variable. Your variables should be named `Var1` and `Var2`. That said, I'd call them `ExcelApp` and `Worksheet` because that gives you more of a chance of understanding at a glance what your code means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the code sample you present, `TVar1` and `TVar2` are *not* global variables, they are local parameters.  They are not marked as `var` params, so they will receive a copy of whatever parameter values are passed into the function call, and any changes made to these local variables will not be passed back to the caller.  It doesn't matter if there are also global variables named `TVar1` and `TVar2` declared elsewhere, in this procedure the local params will take precedence.

If you want to pass modifications back to the caller, declare the parameters as `var` parameters.

```
Procedure TestProc(var TVar1, TVar2 : variant);
```

Comment: The passing of variables by reference is actually what i needed to do  thanks all for your input